# How to re-display a child's component element in the parent?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular11

In my Angular 11 application, I have a component that displays a child component containing some table filters:

**Parent**

```html
<table-filters></table-filters>
<table>
 ...
</table>
```

**Child** (table-filters)

```html
<form>
   <div #companyFilter>
      ...
   </div>
   <div #otherFilter>
      ...
   </div>
</form>
```

How can I get those 2 filters (#companyFilter and #otherFilter) and display them in the parent, separately?

What I want to achieve is something like the following:

```html
<table-filters></table-filters>
<table>
    ...
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="companyFilter"></ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="otherFilter"></ng-container>
</table>
```

This could be done by creating a different component for every single filter, but in my view that's excessive, also because there are many filters.

Comment: I was thinking about a CDK DomPortal or TemplatePortal. This requires `@angular/cdk`

Comment: DomPortal doesn't seem a good solution as the documentation says that "DomPortal moves content as is, so elements with Angular features like bindings or directives may no longer update if moved via DomPortal" and I need bindings and directives to still work on these elements (they are wired to FormControl)

Comment: [What makes you think that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iaryvw?file=package.json,src%2Fmain.ts)? But a TemplatePortal is just as well an option indeed

Answer (score 1):

I will rather use [NgComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) instead of ngTemplate.

In this case I will create a component which will hold these two templates and will pass an injector to this component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `
  <button (click)="company()">Render Company template</button>
  <button (click)="other()">Render Other template</button>
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="currentComponent;
  injector: customInjector"></ng-container>
`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css'],
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  public currentComponent = TableFilterComponent;
  customInjector: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    this.customInjector = Injector.create({
      providers: [{ provide: FILTER, useValue: '' }],
      parent: injector,
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  company() {
    // changing the value of the filter
    this.customInjector = Injector.create({
      providers: [{ provide: FILTER, useValue: 'company' }],
    });
  }

  other() {
    this.customInjector = Injector.create({
      providers: [{ provide: FILTER, useValue: 'other' }],
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbnw8l?file=src%2Fmain.ts) I created for you. Also note the main.ts file for the injector. the example here is with standalone component but you can use conventional approach also